# nhibernate queryOver projection syntax

Tags: c#, nhibernate, projection, queryover

I am trying some code out from a NH 3.0 Cookbook, and wondering why I can't get the code below to compile. I *think* the QueryProjectionBuilder that should make this work is in "NHibernate.Criterion.Lambda" but the using directive for it doesn't help.

The problems are the SelectGroup and SelectAvg parts. Assuming the syntax from the book is correct, can anyone see a missing reference here?

```
namespace Queries.Implementations
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Eg.Core;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Criterion;
using NHibernate.Criterion.Lambda;

    public class QueryOverQueries : CookbookQueriesBase
    {

        public override IEnumerable<NameAndPrice> GetAvgDirectorPrice(ISession session) {
            return _session.QueryOver<Movie>()
                .Select(list => list
                                    .SelectGroup(m => m.Director)
                                    .SelectAvg(m => m.UnitPrice)
                )
                .List<object[]>()
                .Select(props =>
                        new NameAndPrice
                        {
                            Name = (string) props[0],
                            Price = (decimal) props[1]
                        });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `.SelectList` instead of `.Select`