# Linq nhibernate groups and joins

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, group-by

Consider a simple order example (should get the title and quantity ordered for each product):
(note - grouping by Title is not a good answer)

```
var orderQuery = 
    session.Query<OrderLine>()
           .Where(ol => ol.Quantity > 0)
           .GroupBy(ol => ol.Product.Id)
           .Select(x => new 
                        { 
                            productId = x.Key, 
                            quantity = x.Sum(i => i.Quantity) 
                        });

var query = 
    session.Query<Product>()
           .Join(orderQuery, 
                    x => x.Id, 
                    x => x.productId, 
                    (x, p) => new { x.FeedItem.Title, p.quantity });
```

However, this throws a

> could not resolve property: Key of: OrderLine

any ideas?

Comment: tough to tell with your mappings, seems like your OrderLine entity does not have a property called Key? `.Select(x => new { productId = x.Key...`

Comment: Which NHibernate version ? The version 2.1 LINQ provider has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your query using QueryOver and Projections
[Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481907/nhibernate-queryover-projection-syntax)